# How to make a cropped Screenshot as UIImage of a SKNode with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, sprite-kit

The SKNode is very low in the hierarchy

I have tried this in my GameScene (extends SKScene):

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(node.frame.width, node.frame.height), false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)

 var pt:CGPoint=self.scene!.convertPoint(node.position, fromNode: node)

 self.scene?.view?.drawViewHierarchyInRect(CGRect(x: -pt.x+node.frame.width/2.0, y: -pt.y+node.frame.height/2.0, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height), afterScreenUpdates: true)

 var img:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

 UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

without success. The cropping is never correct, and differs depending on the device.
I also tried recursively calculating the position of the node by adding the position of all the parents, with similar results.